# Finding $f\in L^{p}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)\setminus L^{q}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $1\leqslant p<q\leqslant\infty.$  I know then that $L^{q}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)\subsetneq L^{p}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$.  How do I show that it is a proper subgroup? In other words, I am trying to find a function $f\in L^{p}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)\backslash L^{q}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try something along the lines of $\sum n \chi_{E_n}$, where $E_n$ are mutually disjoint sets such that $\mu (E_n) = 1/n^{p+1+\epsilon}$, for a suitably chosen $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following example works:
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\dfrac{1}{x^{1/q}} & \text{if $ x \in (0,1] $}; \\
0                  & \text{elsewhere}.
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of functions, even arbitrarily smooth functions, in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ not in $L^q(\mathbb{R})$. Below is an example of a continuous function in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ not in $L^q(\mathbb{R})$. 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \dfrac1{x^{2/(p+q)}} & x \geq 1\\ x & x \in [0,1) \\ 0 & x<0 \end{cases}$$